# Structuring an Express + GraphQL project

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, structure, graphql

How do you keep a GraphQL API tidy?

I have this simple endpoint with three queriable types and keep a tidy folder structure like such:

```
/api
  |--/entry
      |--/types.js
      |--/queries.js
      |--/mutations.js
  |--/category
      |--/types.js
      |--/queries.js
      |--/mutations.js
  |--/service
      |--/types.js
      |--/queries.js
      |--/mutations.js
  |--index.js
```

The index.js is where I define my root mutation and query, which requires me to explicitly reference my types, queries and mutations, so obviously this file is gonna grow as I add new types, which kinda defeats the point of splitting them in different folders in the first place.

```
// src/routes/api/index.js

const LOGGER = require('../../logger')('routes/api');
const EXPRESS_GRAPHQL = require('express-graphql');

// returned when requiring this module
const routes = function (handler) {

    LOGGER.log('info', 'Setting up api routes.');

    const {
        GraphQLSchema,
        GraphQLObjectType,
    } = require('graphql');

    const categoryQuery = require('./category/queries');
    const {
        updateCategory,
        deleteCategory,
        createCategory
    } = require('./category/mutations');

    const serviceQuery = require('./service/queries');
    const {
        updateService,
        deleteService,
        createService
    } = require('./service/mutations');

    const entryQuery = require('./entry/queries');
    const {
        updateEntry,
        deleteEntry,
        createEntry
    } = require('./entry/mutations');

    const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'rootQuery',
        description: 'This is the root query which holds all possible READ entrypoints for the GraphQL API',
        fields: () => ({
            service: serviceQuery,
            category: categoryQuery,
            entry: entryQuery
        })
    });

    const RootMutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'rootMutation',
        description: 'This is the root mutation which holds all possible WRITE entrypoints for the GraphQL API',
        fields: () => ({
            updateCategory,
            deleteCategory,
            createCategory,
            updateEntry,
            deleteEntry,
            createEntry,
            updateService,
            deleteService,
            createService
        })
    });

    const Schema = new GraphQLSchema({
        query: RootQuery,
        mutation: RootMutation
    });

    return EXPRESS_GRAPHQL({
        schema: Schema,
        pretty: true,
        graphiql: true,
    });
};

module.exports = routes;
```

How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it does not defeat the purpose at all - you have nicely separated concerns in your application, and the only reason for the `index.js` growth is a requirement to explicitly require all your modules.

We struggled with the similar problem and ended up setting a strict interface for what should every model directory (`entry/`, `category/`, `service/`) contain and what should the modules inside export. Thanks to that, you can write a tidy wrapper function, that **dynamically lists all the model directories on startup** and tries to load them, expecting said interface. Thanks to that, you do not have to write any new code in `index.js` at all. You just copypaste a directory, implement exported functions, and they are automatically loaded on application startup.

Remember to add nice error logging to your loader, to avoid cryptic errors when you accidentally break the interface's contract.